# how to generate rechart dynamic x axis values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a graph something like this(ping.apex.sh):[image]

using rechart: http://recharts.org/examples#TinyBarChart

so how would i pass the x axis values as in the above chart ?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the fiddle link on the page you referred to, then you will see how this is done. In short, you dont pass in "x axis values" but the entire dataset as an array of objects containing both the x and the y values to the BarChart component as props like this:

```
<BarChart data={data}></BarChart>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/576yk9so/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=576yk9so)